# Data scraping from online site cgi in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, cgi

Goal: Get tide prediction data for entire year at a particular tidal station (see example below).

Tried: Tips from various posts, including [this exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650502/weather-data-scraping-and-extraction-in-r) about weather data, which seemed most similar. I noticed the site housing the data I want is a cgi; when I select parameters, those parameters aren't reflected in the link address. I'm wholly unfamiliar with dealing with this for data scraping.

```
library(RCurl)
url <- "http://tbone.biol.sc.edu/tide/tideshow.cgi?site=South+Beach%2C+Yaquina+Bay%2C+Oregon&units=f"

s <- getURL(url)
s <- gsub("<br>\n", s)
dat <- read.csv(con <- textConnection(s))
```

This is the first code that actually gave me a product, but it isn't the data in the table. Ideally, I would like to select the options (e.g. 1 year, set start date to Jan. 1). I've never done this and don't know much about HTML programming or developing to know what tools to use with this type of site.

Comment: That site [doesn't really want anyone scraping it](http://tbone.biol.sc.edu/robots.txt). [The software it's displaying](http://www.flaterco.com/xtide/index.html) is free, though.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TideTables/index.html & https://beckmw.wordpress.com/2017/04/12/predicting-tides-in-r/ & http://lukemiller.org/index.php/2016/09/rtide-a-r-package-for-predicting-tide-heights-us-locations-only-currently/ & …OH and especially https://github.com/poissonconsulting/rtide

Comment: I've seen these links. I'm not interested in predicting the tides; it is done for me at this site. This site is important since I'm using it as what "the typical harvester" uses when they plan a trip. I could just export it as a csv, but the goal was to glean the information directly from the site.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a colleague, here is code for scraping data for multiple sites, based on several criteria, from the GUI-based .cgi site.

I had to go back a few steps to the main website where multiple sites (hyperlinks) were listed, select the ones I wanted, apply the criteria that would be selected by the GUI, then format it appropriately into a data frame.

```
library(rvest)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

#define base url for region (ie site where multiple locations are)
url <- "http://tbone.biol.sc.edu/tide/sites_uswest.html"

#read html from page and extract hyperlinks 
#view url to see list of links for multiple locations
l <- url %>%read_html()%>%
  html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")

# grep only tideshow pattern to get vector of site links
# grep allows filtering/subsetting using a partial string 
sites <-  l[grep("*tideshow*", l)]  

# remove everything before 'site=' to get correct formatting for url site names
sites <- gsub(".*site=", "", sites)

#generate vector of sites of interest 
#don't need to use regex to create the vector; 
  #you can manipulate the list of sites however you prefer
  #here, used | for "or" value for selecting multiple sites at once
sites <- sites[grep("(Waldport\\%2C\\+Alsea|South\\+Beach\\%2C\\+Yaquina|Charleston\\%2C\\+Oregon)(?!.*\\%282\\%29)", sites, perl=TRUE)]

#define starting date of data
year <- "2016"
month <- "01"
day <- "01"

#define number of days for prediction
numberofdays = 366 +365 #no. of days in 2016 + no. days in 2017

# lapply through the site vector, x represents site.  
# This will pull data from each site in the vector "sites", and bind it together in a list
o <- lapply(sites, function(x){

  # paste together file path using generalized cgi address and defined parameters
  path<- paste0("http://tbone.biol.sc.edu/tide/tideshow.cgi?type=table;tplotdir=horiz;gx=640;gy=240;caltype=ndp;interval=00%3A01;glen=",
                numberofdays  ,
                ";fontsize=%2B0;units=feet;", 
                "year=", year, ";month=", month, ";day=", day,
                ";hour=00;min=01;",
                "killsun=1;tzone=local;ampm24=24;colortext=black;colordatum=white;colormsl=yellow;colortics=red;colorday=skyblue;colornight=deep-%3Cbr%20%2F%3Eskyblue;colorebb=seagreen;colorflood=blue;site=",
                x,
                ";d_year=;d_month=Jan;d_day=01;d_hour=00;d_min=00"
  )

  # use ReadLines to bring in table from each file.  
  d <- readLines(path, warn=FALSE)

  # extract site name
  site <-  str_extract(string = d[grep("<h2>", d)][1], pattern = "(?<=<h2>)(.*?)(?=</h2>)")

  # extract coordinates
  coord <- gsub(".*<pre>", "",  d[grep("<h2>", d)][1])

  # get tide data lines
  data <- d[grep("\\d{4}[-]\\d{1,2}[-]\\d{1,2}", d) ] 

  # bind columns together
  all <- cbind(site,coord, data)
})

# bind data.frame from list
df <- ldply( o, rbind.data.frame)

# bind site and coordinate columns with split data columns
tides <- cbind(df[c(1,2)] ,  str_split_fixed(df$data, "\\s+", 6))
names(tides) <- c("site", "coordinates", "date", "time", "tz", "depth", "units", "tide")
head(tides)
str(tides)
summary(tides)
```